# Spyder - 2 differents scripts running on the same kernal

Tags: python, spyder

I've just started using spyder, so this might be a stupid question.

I've built an dashboard and want to update it constantly as I alter my statsmodel.

However each time I run it I don't want to have to load in all the packages again.

Is there a way I can just run half the script once when I start the session but then on the same kernal, constantly refresh the rest of the code?

In the same way we can do this in Jupiter notebook with cells.

Comment: are you using dash by plotly? if so, theres a hot-reload option enabled in development mode

Comment: yes thats right - couldn't get it to work in jupyter to moved to spyder

Comment: ive had no problems in spyder, are you in debug mode? `if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)`

Comment: also check https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-plotly-dash/

Comment: do you mean jupyter? Yes I need debug mode and can't get it working

Comment: ive never tried it in jupyter, but that library is supposed to add compatibility. spyder works for me, with a browser tab for the dashboard/webapp

Comment: Spyder has also cells. See [here](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/editor.html#defining-code-cells).